# How do you define the TRACE compile flag in a ASP.NET Web Site project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp.net-2.0, vs-web-site-project

How do you define the TRACE compile flag in a ASP.NET Web Site project? There is no .proj-file and there are no options in any Build-dialogs in Visual Studio that I can find.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and ASP.NET 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

Read this article:

Walkthrough: Integrating ASP.NET Tracing with System.Diagnostics Tracing

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0ectfxd%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Look for the subheading "To compile your application automatically with trace enabled"

You need to put something like this in your web.config:

```
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" 
              extension=".cs" 
              compilerOptions="/d:TRACE"
              type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="1" />
    <compiler language="VB"
              extension=".vb" 
              compilerOptions="/d:Trace=true"
              type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System,                                        Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

Here's the docs on the compiler section in the web.config, though it does not mention Trace stuff:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9x69bzw%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

I just tried it and it works for me.